# Algorithm to calculate a general score and each criteria independently

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, average, weighted-average

Imagine something like booking reviews, where we have for each review some scores by criteria and a general rating.

For the sake of simplicity i will use letters, but imagine A like comfort, B localization, and so on. Available rating is (1-4)

```
                  A   B   C   D 
hotel_review1  |  1   2   3   4 
hotel_review2  |  2   2   3   3
```

---

```
                   A   B   C   D
 user_weighing  |  2   3   2   3
```

---

For the global rating I have this (just a basic weighing avg):

### [image]

For the avg of each criteria, I am doing an arithmetic avg and after that, multiply the result by the user_weighing:

```
A - ((1+2)/2)*2/4 = 0.75
B - ((2+2)/2)*3/4 = 1.5
C - ((3+3)/2)*2/4 = 1.5
D - ((4+3)/2)*3/4 = 2.625
                    -----
                    6.375 / 4 = 1.60
```

So, my problem is that i need a general score, in my case 2.55. However if i look for each score independently, there is a big difference between 2.55 and 1.60. 
There is a better way of doing what I am looking for?

Comment: The problem in the latter method is that you're dividing by 4 which is the wrong value to use. You should divide by the sum of weighings (10) instead (and not divide again at the end.)

Comment: @Juhana did you mean this ((1+2)/2)*10 ?  if i do that for all criteria i will get an extremely high value. Maybe i misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: No, **divide** by 10. `((1+2)/2)*2/10`.

Comment: i would like to know what is the problem of the downvoters at least. the problem is clear and objective, i have all data needed to give an answer and the calcs made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Juhana in the comments, you need to divide by the sum of the weights, which is 10 (2 + 3 + 2 + 3), and not by the number of weights, which is 4:

```
A: ((1+2)/2)*2/10 =  0.3
B: ((2+2)/2)*3/10 =  0.6
C: ((3+3)/2)*2/10 =  0.6
D: ((4+3)/2)*3/10 = 1.05
                   -----
                    2.55
```

However it is a more simple calculation requiring less operations if you leave the divisions by the number of reviews (2) and the sum of weights (10) until the end:

```
A: (1+2)*2 =  6.0
B: (2+2)*3 = 12.0
C: (3+3)*2 = 12.0
D: (4+3)*3 = 21.0
            -----
             51.0 / (2*10) = 2.55
```